# Find the authors of the particular line in git

Tags: git

I'd like to find the authors of the particular line of code which is duplicated across the codebase.

The `-S` parameter find both: addition and deletion, e.g.

```
git log -S"some string"
```

I'd like to find an addition only, and then count who copied this line and how many times (but for this second task I can write some script which parses git log).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `git blame` [options](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame), I think `-L` and `-C` (multiple times) should do the trick.